# Webs de localhost en una web en línea

Tags: javascript, nodejs, web, localhost

Me gustaría saber si es posible que teniendo una web con NodeJS en ngrok (https://miweb.ngrok-free.app), al poner una sub página, por ejemplo "https://miweb.ngrok-free.app/mipagina2" te mostrara la información de otra web en NodeJS.

Es decir, tengo dos webs en NodeJS, una pública conectada a Ngrok y otra que solo es accesible desde localhost:puerto. Y lo que quiero hacer es que la información de mi segunda página web (localhost) se mande a la web principal (la que está en línea) y así mostrar los datos de la web local en línea.

Espero que se me haya entendido y gracias de antemano por los que os molestéis en ayudarme.